# How to use Micronaut with Spring Jdbctemplate and transactions?

Tags: java, transactions, jdbctemplate, micronaut

#### Expected Behavior

When using the [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation I expect the database operations to fall into a transaction scope and if any step fails the rollback should be done.

#### Actual Behaviour

In the current scenario, even with an  [@Transactional](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html)  annotation, in case of an operation failure, the rollback is not done, causing inconsistency

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. In your database apply the [DDL](https://github.com/viniciusxyz/micronaut-transaction-failed/blob/master/src/main/resources/SQL/DDL/DEPOSIT.sql) script
2. Perform the following operation on the database to create an account *insert into ACCOUNTS (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, BALANCE) values ​​('0000001',0.0)*
3. Run the application and execute the curl below:

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/deposit' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "accountNumber": "0000001",
  "amount": 999.20
}'
```

You will see a DataIntegrityViolationException being thrown, this is because the history table has an ill-defined field with a decimal amount(2,2) and the deposit amount does not match, in this case I expected the account balance update to be reversed , however this does not occur.

I saw that there is already an issue about problem #651 that was closed, but the micronaut data documentation suggests that this feature works because in item 10 there is the following text:

```
In addition to this dependency you will need either spring-orm (for Hibernate) or spring-jdbc (for JDBC) on your classpath to enable support for Spring-based transaction management:
```

Could you clarify this point please? We are planning to migrate some applications from spring to micronaut and they are all developed with jdbctemplate so the transition would be a lot easier if I could make this point work, maybe I've lost something in the documentation or I'm getting it wrong at some point, thanks for the good work.

#### Environment Information

Operating System: Windows 11
JDK: Zulu JDK 11.0.12
Maven 3.6.3
Micronaut 2.5.4

#### Example Application

https://github.com/viniciusxyz/micronaut-transaction-failed

#### Version

2.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem.

Just replace the dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-data-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

per:

```xml
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.micronaut.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>micronaut-spring</artifactId>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
```